# Change the JVectorMap legend position

Tags: javascript, css, jvectormap

I need to change the position of JVectorMap legend box.

Anybody know how to change legend box to left botton position?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem using CSS styles.

```
.jvectormap-legend-cnt-v{
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
    top: auto;
}
```

And

```
.jvectormap-legend-cnt-h{
   left: 0;
   right: auto;
}
```